# Disable select attribute after another select option with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have -/+50 select option with looping. i want disable selection after select another selection According to id.

**Javascript code (hide option) :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(element)
{
  d=document;
  drops = d.getElementsByName('drop').length;
  opts = 99;
  for (i=1;i<drops+1;i++)
  {
    if (element.id != 'drop'+i && element.value != '0')
    {
      for (z=0;z<opts;z++)
      {
        if (d.getElementById('drop'+i).options[z].value == element.value)
        {
          d.getElementById('drop'+i).options[z] = null;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Javascript Code (disable select) :**

```
<script>
function myDisable() {
    document.getElementById("drop15").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("drop19").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("drop10").disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

**Html Code :**

```
<select id="drop1" name="drop" onchange="check(this); myDisable();"> 
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="3">One</option>
  <option value="5">Two</option>
  <option value="1">Three</option>
</select>
```

----------- loopping select +/-50 -----------------

i want to disable selection from input number for amount to be disabled

Comment: d.getElementById('drop1'+i).... you missed '1' in id drop1

Comment: are you  want disable options or select box ? because disabling select box working fine with your code

Comment: i want disable select box . . . dynamic number id @ShailendraSharma